# Bayes estimators for two coins with different probability of heads

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, beta-distribution

I would like some help with the following parameter estimation problem.

We have two coins: the first has probability $\theta$ for heads and the second $1-\theta$ .
The  prior for $\theta$ is Beta(2,3).
We choose randomly one coin and we count the number of heads (r.v. X) occurred in n tosses. We want to find the Bayes estimator for squared error loss.

The way, I approached the problem was the following.
First, I estimated the posterior probabilities of $\theta$ for each of the two cases w.r.t.  which of the coins had been selected. (What changes between the two cases, is the second parameter of the binomial that has to do with the probability of success.)

$\pi( \theta| x)  \propto \mathcal{L}(\theta ; x)\pi( \theta)  \\
\pi( \theta| x) =   Beta(2+x,n+3-x)$
for the first coin

$\pi( \theta| x) \propto \mathcal{L}(\theta ; x)  \pi( \theta) \\
\pi( \theta| x) =Beta(n+2-x,x+3) $ for the second coin

Then, using the Law of total expectation I arrived at

$\pi( \theta| x) = \frac{1}{2}Beta(n+2-x,x+3) +\frac{1}{2}Beta(n+2-x,x+3)$
And, by taking the mean value of the posterior I concluded that the Bayes estimator is
$d=\mathbb{E}(\pi( \theta| x)) = \mathbb{E}[ \, \frac{1}{2}Beta(n+2-x,x+3) +\frac{1}{2}Beta(n+2-x,x+3)] \, \\
d=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[ \,  Beta(n+2-x,x+3)] \,  +\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[ \, Beta(n+2-x,x+3)] \,  \\
d=\frac{1}{2}\frac{n+2}{n+5}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{n+2-x}{n+5}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{n+4}{n+5}
$

I am not sure about the result since the number of successes (x) does not appear at all.
However, this makes sense to me, since a higher X means high $\theta$ when he have selected
the first coin, but low $\theta$ when he have selected
the second. And since, we choose each coin randomly, this information cancels out.

Could you tell if I addressed the problem correctly? And if not, could you tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: This forum is about research in mathematics, not for questions like this.

Comment: It might help if you just specify the likelihood of the model and see whether it has any information about the parameter. Forget about the prior, what is $p(x \mid \theta)$?

Comment: The $p(x | \theta)$ is a binomial distribution in both cases. In the case for the first coin it is $Bin(n,\theta)$ and in the case for the second  coin it is $Bin(n,1-\theta)$ where n denotes the number of tosses.